# C# Login page problems. MyDatabaseEntities

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I am new to programming and I got a question.
I followed a turtorial to make a login. But my code will not work and I keep getting this error: 
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'MyDatabaseEntities' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Also when I click login it won't redirect too my after login page.
Please keep your explanation quite simple because I'm kind off new too programming.

Here are my pages with code: 
HomeController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace DNDB.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(Gebruiker u)
    {
        // this action is for handle post (login) 
        if (ModelState.IsValid) // this is check validity 
        {
            using (MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities())
            {
                var v = dc.Gebruiker.Where(a =>             a.Gebruikersnaam.Equals(u.Gebruikersnaam) && a.Wachtwoord.Equals(u.Wachtwoord)).FirstOrDefault();
                if (v != null)
                {
                    Session["LogedUserId"] = v.UserId.ToString();
                    Session["LogedEmailAdres"] = v.EmailAdres.ToString();
                    return RedirectToAction("AfterLogin");
                }
            }
        }
        return View(u);
    }


    public ActionResult AfterLogin()
    {
        if (Session["LogedUserId"] != null)
        {
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }   
}
}
```

Login.cshtml

```
@model DNDB.Gebruiker
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}

<h2>Login</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
if (@ViewBag.Message != null)
{
    <div style="border: 1px solid red"> 
        @ViewBag.Message
    </div> 
}
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(a => a.Gebruikersnaam)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Gebruikersnaam)</td>
        <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Gebruikersnaam)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.LabelFor(a => a.Wachtwoord)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.PasswordFor(a => a.Wachtwoord)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Wachtwoord)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
}

@* This below line is for create javascript section 
*@

@section Scripts{
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Afterlogin.cshtml

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "AfterLogin";
}

<h2>After Login</h2>
@if (Session["LogedUserId"] != null)
{
<text>
    Welcome @Session["LogedUserId"].ToString()
</text>
}
```

Gebruiker.cs                (This is my user.cs)

```
namespace DNDB
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

[Table("Gebruiker")]
public partial class Gebruiker
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public string Gebruikersnaam { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public string Wachtwoord { get; set; }

    [StringLength(128)]
    public string EmailAdres { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
}
```

Gebruikersmodel.cs

```
namespace DNDB
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public partial class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string EmailAdres { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Voer een gebruikersnaam in.",     AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Gebruikersnaam { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Voer een wachtwoord in.", AllowEmptyStrings    = false)]
    [DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.Password)]
    public string Wachtwoord { get; set; }
}
}
```

MyDatabaseEntities.cs

```
namespace DNDB
{
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;

public partial class MyDatabaseEntities : DbContext
{
    public MyDatabaseEntities()
        : base("name=MyDatabaseEntities")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Gebruiker> Gebruiker { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Gebruiker>()
            .Property(e => e.Gebruikersnaam)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Gebruiker>()
            .Property(e => e.Wachtwoord)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Gebruiker>()
            .Property(e => e.EmailAdres)
            .IsUnicode(false);
    }
}
}
```

I hope you guys can help me out with this.

Comment: for as far as I can see, you're missing `MyDatabaseEntities` (and hai, Marijn)

Comment: What should it be? Kind off confused about this error because it isn't displaying in the turtorial I used. Source: http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2014/03/how-to-create-login-page-using-aspnet-mvc4.html

Comment: you should have a database, create an entity of that database and use that, have you also followed their tutorial on how to make a registration form?

Comment: I added the MyDatabaseEntities but now I'm getting this error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0229 Ambiguity between 'Gebruiker.Gebruikersnaam' and 'Gebruiker.Gebruikersnaam' DNDB

Comment: In which file do you get this error?